# Exception in thread java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: java, multithreading, indexoutofboundsexception

If I run this code without any changes, I get that error 
*Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1*

If I remove syntax of comment line **System.out.println(data);**, I don't get any error.

I don't want to print any situation of my app. Variable of **data** is important for me. How can I solve this problem without using **System.out**?

Could you help me?

```
private static ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList();
private BufferedReader in1;
private String[] s;
private String data;
...
...
...
...

while (close) {
            try {
                if ((data = in1.readLine()) != null) {
                    //System.out.println(data); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                    if (data.contains("#")) {
                        s = data.split("#");
                        if (s[0].equals("enter")) {
                            if (s[1].equals("ok")) {
                            } else if (s[1].equals("no")) {
                            } else {
                                synchronized (myList) {
                                    myList.set(myList.indexOf(id), s[1]);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: do you know what an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 is?

Comment: What is `id`? (In the line `myList.set(myList.indexOf(id), s[1]);`) I'm willing to bet that it's `-1`

Comment: who else is using the arrayList? those threads have to lock on the list too.

Comment: In addition to what GBlodgett said, some other thread may have messed up the value of `id`. In that case, your list won't contain that value. The method `myList.indexOf(id)` returns `-1`, causing `myList.set(...)` to throw an exception

Comment: id its just a simple elements of class. Initially "String id;" and after the constructive method id is gaining new value. It never has a null value. Arraylist is synchronized (locked) in everywhere

Comment: I actually replace value of arraylist from old to new. `myList.set(myList.indexOf(id), s[1]);` so id is a member of the arraylist(myList)

Comment: myList.set(myList.indexOf(id), s[1]), this line may cause the exception if given id is not present in the list.

Comment: You may try https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html instead of arraylist

Comment: You should show all places in your code where `id` is assigned. There is obviously a scenario when the value of `id` is not in your list.

Comment: Also the code works fine when I delete the top line **synchronized (myList){}**.

Comment: You say in your comment "id is a member of the arraylist(myList)". Can you prove it?